# doAnswer and ClassCastException

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to stub a method invocation

```
SpotApi.APIlistCandlesticksRequest req = spotApi.listCandlesticks(coinPair);
```

to return different values for different invocations, with:

```
  @Mock private SpotApi.APIlistCandlesticksRequest 
  mockAPIlistCandlesticksRequest, mockAPIlistCandlesticksRequest2;
  . . . 
   doAnswer(inv-> new Answer<SpotApi.APIlistCandlesticksRequest>() {
  private int count = 0;
  @Override
  public SpotApi.APIlistCandlesticksRequest answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) {
    count++;
    if (count == 1) {
      return mockAPIlistCandlesticksRequest;
    } else if (count == 2) {
      return mockAPIlistCandlesticksRequest2;
    }
    return null;
  }
}).when(mockSpotApi).listCandlesticks(COINPAIR);
```

but it fails with

> : class com.gateiobot.macd.MACDCalculationTest$1 cannot be cast to class io.gate.gateapi.api.SpotApi$APIlistCandlesticksRequest (com.gateiobot.macd.MACDCalculationTest$1 and io.gate.gateapi.api.SpotApi$APIlistCandlesticksRequest are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are making an `Answer` which returns an answer which returns the `SpotApi.APIlistCandlesticksRequest`. You see, the construct `inv -> new Answer() { ...}` is a function returning an `Answer`. When given as argument to `doAnswer` it implicitly becomes an implementation of the `Answer` functional interface, per the contract of `doAnswer`.

Just keep one. If you keep the labda it will be more awkward to keep state (the `count`), so you can just keep the inner class:

```java
doAnswer(new Answer<SpotApi.APIlistCandlesticksRequest>() { // NO inv ->
  private int count = 0;
  @Override
  public SpotApi.APIlistCandlesticksRequest answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) {
    count++;
    if (count == 1) {
      return mockAPIlistCandlesticksRequest;
    } else if (count == 2) {
      return mockAPIlistCandlesticksRequest2;
    }
    return null;
  }
}).when(mockSpotApi).listCandlesticks(COINPAIR);
```